# collapse list column elements to a string

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, purrr

I would like to collapse a subcategory into a comma-delimited string for display.
This is what I have.

```
library(tibble)
eats <- tribble(
  ~food,~variety,
  "fruit","cherry",
  "fruit","apple",
  "fruit","peach",
  "nut","cashew",
  "nut","almonds"
)
eats
#> # A tibble: 5 x 2
#>   food  variety
#>   <chr> <chr>  
#> 1 fruit cherry 
#> 2 fruit apple  
#> 3 fruit peach  
#> 4 nut   cashew 
#> 5 nut   almonds
```

This is what I want:

```
eats2 <- tribble(
  ~food,~varieties,
  "fruit","cherry, apple, peach",
  "nut","cashew, almond"
)
eats2  
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   food  varieties           
#>   <chr> <chr>               
#> 1 fruit cherry, apple, peach
#> 2 nut   cashew, almond
```

This what I've tried:

```
eats %>% 
  nest(data=variety) %>% 
  mutate(data = paste(data,collapse = ""))
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   food  data                                                                    
#>   <chr> <chr>                                                                   
#> 1 fruit "list(variety = c(\"cherry\", \"apple\", \"peach\"))list(variety = c(\"~
#> 2 nut   "list(variety = c(\"cherry\", \"apple\", \"peach\"))list(variety = c(\"~
```

Nope.

```
eats %>% 
  nest(data=variety) %>% 
  map(~.x %>% mutate(varieties=paste(data,collapse = "")))
#> Error in UseMethod("mutate"): no applicable method for 'mutate' applied to an object of class "character"
```

> Created on 2022-07-01 by the reprex package (v2.0.1)

Also nope. What is the right way to do this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following code using `summarise` and `toString`:

```r
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
eats <- tribble(
  ~food,~variety,
  "fruit","cherry",
  "fruit","apple",
  "fruit","peach",
  "nut","cashew",
  "nut","almonds"
)
eats %>%
  group_by(food) %>%
  summarise(varieties = toString(variety)) %>%
  ungroup()
#> # A tibble: 2 × 2
#>   food  varieties           
#>   <chr> <chr>               
#> 1 fruit cherry, apple, peach
#> 2 nut   cashew, almonds
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: That was easier than I thought. Thanks.  It shows how my base-R skills have atrophied.  I forgot all about toString.

Answer (score 2):

Like @Quinten's solution, just using `paste` instead of `toString`:

```
library(dplyr)

eats %>%
  group_by(food) %>%
  summarise(varieties = paste(variety, collapse = ", ")) %>%
  ungroup()
```

```
  food  varieties           
  <chr> <chr>               
1 fruit cherry, apple, peach
2 nut   cashew, almonds
```